# How to read a JSON value?

Tags: android

this is my json response

```
{
  "status": true,
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "id": "14"
  }
}
```

how to read this values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the help of [Google's GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library built for exact your pupose.

```
YourPojoClass model = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, YourPojoClass.class);
```

Convert your json to PojoModel by using [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Create a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

To get a specific boolean

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getBoolean("status");
```

To get a specific String

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("message");
```

To get a specific Integer

```
int aJsonInteger = jObject.getInt("code");
```